# neovim ruby/rails omnicomplete

Tags: neovim, autocompletion, filetype-ruby

I'm trying to get omnicomplete working in neovim (0.3.4) on debian 10 with Ruby 2.6.6 (rbenv).

I have these plugins:

```
Plug 'vim-ruby/vim-ruby'                " ruby                                                                                                                        
Plug 'tpope/vim-rails'                  " rails
```

With these settings:

```
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_buffer_loading = 1                                                                                                     
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_classes_in_global = 1                                                                                                  
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_rails = 1
```

I get this error when trying omnicomplete:

> option 'omnifunc' is not set

If I add this:

```
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby set omnifunc=rubycomplete#Complete
```

I get this error:

> Error: falling back to syntax completion
>   E117: Unknown function: rubycomplete#Complete

But after I click this error away it seems to work?
What am I doing wrong?
(I'm not interested in other plugins like deoplete, ...)

**Update:**
When I change

```
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby set omnifunc=rubycomplete#Complete
```

to

```
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
```

it seems to work. Not sure if that is the correct way?

**update 2:**

In Neovim you can check if Ruby is installed with `:checkhealth`.

In Debian 10 you can install ruby-neovim if you use the system Ruby version.

Since I use rbenv I did this:

```
gem install neovim
```

.vimrc settings:

```
let g:ruby_host_prog = '~/.rbenv/shims/neovim-ruby-host'
let g:ruby_path = system('echo $HOME/.rbenv/shims')
let g:rubycomplete_buffer_loading = 1
let g:rubycomplete_classes_in_global = 1
let g:rubycomplete_rails = 1
```

There was also a bug in vim-ruby for the completion, but that is now fixed: https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/pull/415

Comment: What if you take the global variables out of the autocommand? Theyre global, and it shouldn’t do any harm to just set them in your vimrc.

Comment: good suggestion, but it doesn't make a difference

Comment: The vim-ruby plugin should already [set](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/blob/fbf85d106a2c3979ed43d6332b8c26a72542754d/ftplugin/ruby.vim#L48,L50) `omnifunc` to `rubycomplete#Complete` if the filetype is `ruby` **and** your Vim has support for Ruby. Can you check that `:set ft?` returns `filetype=ruby`? Can you check that `:version` includes `+ruby` in the list of features?

Comment: +1 to what @D.BenKnoble said. Set those globals in your vimrc directly, not as autocmd's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message you're getting, it seems your Vim doesn't have Ruby support compiled in.

See [this code snippet](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/autoload/rubycomplete.vim#L20,L26):

```
if !has('ruby')
    call s:ErrMsg( "Error: Rubycomplete requires vim compiled with +ruby" )
    call s:ErrMsg( "Error: falling back to syntax completion" )
    " lets fall back to syntax completion
    setlocal omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
    finish
endif
```

The error message in bold is the one you're seeing. (If you type `:messages` you'll probably see the other, more explicit error message, about support for Ruby missing.)

You can confirm that Ruby support is missing by using the `:version` command in Vim to get a list of features. You'll see `-ruby`, since you're missing Ruby support. (You'd see `+ruby` if it was available.)

From your question, you're using NeoVim on Debian Buster, so maybe try installing the [`ruby-neovim` package](https://packages.debian.org/buster/ruby-neovim) to see if that solves the problem and enables Ruby support on your NeoVim?

---

> `set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete` seems to work. Not sure if that is the correct way?

That is going to give you *some* completion, but probably not as rich as the Ruby-specific completion from `rubycomplete`.

The `syntaxcomplete#Complete` function will use Vim's syntax highlighting rules to offer insert completion, which for the most part covers language keywords that are highlighted by syntax rules.

See [`:help ft-syntax-omni`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#ft-syntax-omni):

> Vim has the ability to color syntax highlight nearly 500 languages.  Part of
>   this highlighting includes knowing what keywords are part of a language.  Many
>   filetypes already have custom completion scripts written for them, the
>   syntaxcomplete plugin provides basic completion for all other filetypes.  It
>   does this by populating the omni completion list with the text Vim already
>   knows how to color highlight.  It can be used for any filetype and provides a
>   minimal language-sensitive completion.

So this might be adequate and better than nothing... But I'd expect you'd get superior completion by using `rubycomplete` instead.

---

> With these settings:
>
> ```
> autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_buffer_loading = 1
> autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_classes_in_global = 1
> autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_rails = 1
> ```

These are globals and are intended to be set *directly* from your vimrc and not in a filetype autocmd.

This might be important since you might have ordering issues (these are only set after the vim-ruby plugins try to inspect them, producing the incorrect result), or you might get different behavior from the first Ruby file you edit to the subsequent ones (since the first one sets them *globally*, they'll already be set when the second file is opened.)

Just avoid these issues altogether by setting them directly, as intended:

```
let g:rubycomplete_buffer_loading = 1
let g:rubycomplete_classes_in_global = 1
let g:rubycomplete_rails = 1
```

Comment: yes, I didn't had ruby-neovim installed. Now the error is gone, but I get the message 'pattern not found'. (also in vim-nox). Syntaxcomplete seems to give better results? (In a model I try to complete 'val')

Comment: could be a problem with system ruby vs rbenv ruby. I'll have to investigate, but the problem I asked is solved.

Comment: See `:help ft-ruby-omni` for more on what to expect from Ruby ommi completion. Note it uses `'require'` option to find other files in your project (but it seems you can't even complete from the same file.) Also, I'd expect vim-ruby and vim-rails to take care of that setting for you... Unfortunately I don't know much more about rails or ruby... Yeah it could be related to rbenv ruby! Good luck, I hope you'll figure it out!